# Raspberry Pi operating system kills the compiled qt4 executable without any error

Tags: c, qt, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm trying to compile the [Elmer FEM software](https://github.com/ElmerCSC/elmerfem) on Raspberry Pi OS (AFIK formerly known as Raspbian). Following these instructions:

1. `sudo apt install cmake gfortran libopenblas-dev libqt4-dev libqwt-dev`
2. inside the build directory `cmake .. -DWITH_OpenMP:BOOLEAN=TRUE -DWITH_MPI:BOOLEAN=FALSE -DWITH_ELMERGUI:BOOLEAN=TRUE`
3. `make -j3`
4. `sudo make install`

I managed to compile the software with no errors (... load of warnings though!). Now heading towards `/usr/local/bin` and running `./ElmerGUI` the software icon appears for a minute or two and then disappears with no prompt or errors, showing just a `Killed` message in the terminal:

Given that there is no error messages I have no clue what is going wrong leading to the abrupt termination of the software. I would appreciate if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can resolve it.

My environment:

- Hardware: Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2
- Operating system: Linux raspberrypi 5.4.51-v7+ ... armv7l GNU/Linux

**P.S.** Following [this comment on Discord](https://discordapp.com/channels/412182089279209474/686694190133805106/754437611472289852), I did `grep -r "Killed" .` in the project folder, which returned no results. I'm almost certain the `Killed` message is from the OS itself.

Comment: @francescalus The Elmer software is mainly Fortran. I think that tag was required.

Comment: If you think [tag:fortran] is required, feel free to add it back in (I won't remove it again).  But without indications of issues with the code, such as the warnings you mention, I don't think there's much a Fortran expert can say to answer this question.

Comment: @francescalus well, at this moment I have no clue if it has anything to do with Fortran or not. so will not add it back, unless people realize it is somehow related.

Comment: You should compile it in debug and run through gdb to have an idea. The kernel is probably killing the process, but there may be several reasons. You could also look if the kernel reported something interesting in dmesg.

Comment: @Foad , while I completely have no idea .. I noticed there are three possible ways to compile (_Without_ , _With MPI_ , _With ElmreGUI_) .... and your build instruction does not match any ... Did you try alternatives ?

Comment: Did you tried `strace` to see where it exits?

Comment: @jeb . no I didn't. how can I do that?

Comment: `strace ./ElmerGui` it will flood you with system calls. Normally, at the end of the output will be the relevant calls (the failing ones)